# How to include github html file in html with php ?

Tags: php, html, github

Suppose I have a HTML file as --
https://raw.github.com/USER/PROJECT/master/file.html

How do I make it available in my website. One method will be using the rawgithub service and then using something like `iframe` but I want the HTML to be inherited in my website so that Google shows it in the searches.

php's include function looks like doing the trick but I don't get it to work. I simply use
`include "<file_full_URL>";`

Comment: do you want it to show as code or you want to display the html?

Comment: Yes I want to display the HTML. btw how you will show it as code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$url = "http://www.example.com"; //write your raw.github.com URL
$gethtml = file_get_contents($url);
echo $gethtml; //output the content in the page
```

Answer (score 3):

In PHP you can use the [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) function to grab files over the internet.

```
$html = file_get_contents('https://raw.github.com/USER/PROJECT/master/file.html');
echo $html;
```

Your pages will be slower if you do this, though. Setting up a cronjob that downloads the file to your server periodically, and then serving it from your server, is a much better idea.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to show it as code you can use [this](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/intelligist/) jquery plugin for that